# RabbitMQ Event Subscribers - which is good? Windows service or Http Services (REST API)

Tags: rest, docker, rabbitmq, windows-services, httpservice

I am working on Microsoft technologies and the environment is Windows server 2012. we have a requirement to use RabbitMQ which has multiple events needs to be subscribed by any of the services hosted in windows either in IIS or as windows service.

Which option would be more suitable to act as RabbitMQ subscriber?

Here are the options which I considered

- Single Windows service subscribed for multiple events separate
- windows service subscribed for each event Http service (REST API)
- hosted in IIS subscribed for multiple events
- use Docker containers to host Http service which subscribes to events. Though, currently, my company is not ready to opt container environments.